# Div that stays centered on window resize and overflows to both the left and right

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm essentially trying to create this effect:
https://squareup.com/

but I cannot figure out how to get my div to overflow to the left while it stays centered on the page when the window is resized.

Comment: https://www.pageblox.com/generate use their templates.

Comment: Have you tried `margin: 0 auto;`?

Comment: @HanletEscaño I need the div to overflow to the left of the page, I know how to layout the page. Torr3nt, yes I have, that works for centering it but it wont overflow left.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mdesdev/nUxPd/)

**HTML**

```
<div class="content">

  <div class="wrapper">

    <h1>CONTENT</h1>

  </div>

</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.content {
  background: url(../bg-image.png) center no-repeat;
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
}
.wrapper {
  width: 980px;
  height: 400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: I need the image to be a static size and overflow off the left hand side of the page when the frame (window) is resized in your fiddle the left hand side of the image stays statically on the left hand side of the page while the right side overflows.

Comment: Actually, is there any way to lock the left overflow once it hits a certain point on the resizing (in this fiddle, the "content" area)

Comment: I don't understand, can you explain it a little better?

Comment: So lets say the image is 1285 pixels and the area in the middle where the content is contained is 925px is there anyway to stop the image from overflowing to the left once the width of the frame gets down to 924px?

Comment: From what I see at squareup.com they use CSS media queries, I'll try it in Fiddle...

Comment: Finally... [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mdesdev/nUxPd/) updated, I just needed image with same height as content.